# Expressing the transitivity of $a|b$ in logic notation

Tags: logic, notation

I do not know how to ask my question  properly but please allow me to state it. I want to express this claim in logical notation. "For all integers a,b,c if a|b and b|c then a|c."

The logical notation involves things like $\implies$, $\vee$, $\wedge$, $\forall$, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sign $|$ is allowed:
$$\forall a\forall b\forall c((a|b\land b|c)\implies a|c).$$

Comment: Can ∀abc be the same as ∀a∀b∀c?

Comment: Is a usual abbreviation.

Comment: please what do you mean if the sign | is allowed? can it be expressed in another sign?

Comment: $a|b$ is, by definition, $\exists x\ ax=b$.